# Is it possible to reliably nest find -exec commands in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, find, xargs

I need to fix permissions on a large number of files from a subset of directories on a large nfs volume.

In building up a solution, I started by using find to get a list of the directories I want:

```
find . -type d -regex "^./[0-9]*"
```

The directories all start with a number.

I can successfully use this to exec a 2nd find.  That find gets files that exclude a few filenames I don't want to process:

```
find . -type d -regex "^./[0-9]*" -exec find {} -type f \( ! -iname '.*' ! -name 'async.log' \) \;
```

This all works great and returns the list of files I need to process.

*Now to the problem:*

What I really want is to use the 2nd find to -exec chmod 644.  I have found a way to do this using xargs that seems to work fine.  In the examples here I'm using echo just to verify the list of files being returned.

```
find . -type d -regex "^./[0-9]*" | xargs -I dirname find dirname -type f \( ! -iname '.*' ! -name 'async.log' \) -exec echo {} \;
```

But what I'd like do is just use -exec with my chained find commands, as it is many times faster than piping the results to xargs, but something goes wrong with the results:

```
find . -type d -regex "^./[0-9]*" -exec find {} -type f \( ! -iname '.*' ! -name 'async.log' \) \; -exec echo {} \;
```

When I send output to a file, there is a discrepancy and the nested find command seems to stop before full completion.

When comparing the 2 files, the xargs version has 173125 lines, whereas the nested find command only has 173060 lines.

The last line in the find version shows truncation:

```
./104/5734c420e70d8.pdf
./104
```

I am at a loss to explain this, or come up with a way to debug or workaround the problem.  Any ideas on how I might get my find -only solution working?

Comment: **it is many times faster than piping the results to xargs** Unlikely to happen since `-exec` when terminated with `\;` spawns a new shell for every entry found by `find` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be simplier if you use `find` only one time.

The following solution will work as long all your directories you want to search are in the same directory.

```
find {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}* -type f \( ! -iname '.*' ! -name 'async.log' \) -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Search in current directory all directories beginning by a number, exclude file beginning by a dot, exclude file named `async.log` and apply command `chmod 644` to file found.

Comment: You can use `{0..9}*` instead of `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}*`